# Partition data but dropping elements between each sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Is there a neat way to partition a list into sublists of fixed length $n$, discarding a fixed number $k$ elements between each one?

E.g for $n=3, k=1$,

```
f[Range[1,11],3,1]={{1,2},{4,5},{7,8},{10,11}}
```

I can do it with

```
Take[#, 2] & /@ Partition[pts, 3]
```

(or wrapped into a function) but I was expecting `Partition` to be able to do it in one call.

My use-case has a list of length <10,000, splitting into chunks of 100 with a small offset of 5 or so, so speed is not really an issue for me, but it is always interesting to see how to do these things quickly.

Comment: `Partition[Range[1, 11], 2, 3]`. From the docs (Generalizations and extensions): _Skip elements by using an offset larger than the block size_

Comment: Thanks @user1066. Should have studied the docs more carefully